# Failing local running slick slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

I'm using [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) plugin, implementing the most basic examples that works at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/5ox31m2a/) but doesn't work once I local run the slick slider.

It seems once I run it locally I can't get the results if I'd run it in jsfiddle, but I don't know what is causing the problem.

The local run output: [image]

What's causing the code to show me different results while local running it?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    .slider {
      width: 650px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      cssEase: 'linear'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

JS Console output:

> jquery.min.js:3 [Intervention] Slow network is detected. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more
>   details. Fallback font will be used while loading:
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/fonts/slick.woff

Yet, my slow network runs it fine at jsfiddle, I don't believe it's related to my issue.

Comment: try running js min from local folder

Comment: @AkhilAravind same result, tried that by following the slick slider usage.

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it too works fine. There must be something in your local copy which is affecting it. I'd suggest inspecting the DOM to see what styling is being applied to the relevant elements and where it's coming from, as this appears to be a CSS issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I really don't know where to look for it, tried inspecting tool in google chrome but there is nothing essential there.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file normally on the browser, it won't work.

Try serving the `index.html` file from `localhost`.
It will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the css and try. Slide height is taking 100% height

```css
.slick-slide { height:auto;}
```